# why would the bodies of an immortal sorceress decay at an accelerated rate?

Tags: magic

A dark sorceress has discovered a dark form of immortality. A being can transfer their soul to a younger body and take their place as long as it is an individual in their family or generational line. She performed an ancient ritual on herself to ensure that her spirit will be passed down through her female descendants. At the moment of birth, her soul will be transferred into her daughter's body, snuffing out the life within. She has effectively reincarnated herself through her own children multiple times through this method, and has managed to live for hundreds of years.

However, there has been a developing problem over the last few centuries that she has begun to notice: the bodies that she takes over eventually starts to rot. Each successive body begins to decay faster than the previous one, forcing her to perform the process sooner and more frequently. With her bodies constantly dying quicker, she has less time to spend in them to find a way to stop the process, and is running short on time.

Why would this be the case?

Comment: Because, whatever reason you want to use, that's a story thing not anything else.

Comment: Could you list some criteria for an answer? It could be anything from "magic" to "randomly selected bad bodies" right now. It's also insanely easy to come up with reasons, I just named two without having to think about it. Please try to specify

Comment: It's all the hormones in them hamburgers. They're making people age faster, I tell ya.

Comment: @Renan You have a true gift for the one-liner comment on this kind of question.

Comment: Simple answer. Every generation is a generation further from the sorceress' original body. Each daughter has less of the witch's genes in her and more of her various partners'. Eventually the daughter she is trying to inhabit will be so dissimilar to her that the spell won't recognize her as a descendant capable of housing her soul.

Answer (score 4):

**Transplant rejection**

In the same way that the body recognizes, rejects, and eventually destroys transplanted organs (that aren't carefully prepared, at any rate), so too does it fight back against the intruding spirit. The sorceress's magic means the body can never win, but the strain of this internal battle eventually wears out her hosts.

But it's worse than that. Because the soul-transferring magic isn't perfect, she brings a little bit of each previous host with her. The first host was fighting one intruding spirit. The second, two spirits. The third, three - and so on. Each time, the rejection comes faster because there are even more foreign entities trying to share the same body.

Comment: Imagine her having a psychotic break and all those hidden voices coming to the fore. I'm imagining soooo many stories now :)

Comment: @EveryBitHelps I think you have your cause and effect backwards - clearly the psychotic break is *because* she has all those voices in her head.

Comment: Lol. I was thinking more along the lines of her managing to cope and bury those voices (probably unwittingly and totally unaware of it), something *else* comes along to mess with her already strained mind, then she breaks and starts slowly/rapidly hearing these immature half-formed voices which messes with her even more. Many different cause and effects to make some stories around :)

Comment: While I really like the potentials this answer creates I wish it wasn't wasted on a question that was so badly suited to the site.

Comment: @Ash Since the question is about achieving an effect. Something WB encourages & welcomes. Both question & answer are appropriate. This is about building a world where soul transfers are part of the furniture.

Answer (score 2):

Witch did follow Test Driven Development, didn'she?
She obviously tested on hamsters, rabbits, reproducing the steps and got a control group to compare. .... nah.

What happens is you found a bug. 90% was trasferred, not the whole. So now she is withering earlier than expected.

Answer (score 1):

Black mana consumes/destroys life energy. If a dark sorcerer possesses a living being and uses black magic this shall cause the rotting as a side effect. If he becomes more powerful/elder the amount of black mana he is capable of channeling should also increase, which accelerates the rotting.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, dietah! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. Have fun!